Cover radiator enclosure with neoprene or polyurethane sheets to reduce overheating? Recommendations?
I've got hissing apartment radiators that don't close all the way in a poorly maintained building with cheapo landlords. Every winter we have had issues with radiators pumping out heat all day long followed by all night long without stopping.
These are not traditional metal cast iron radiators. These are under-the-window, 1940s-era convective baseboard-style copper finned heating elements that are housed in a metal, painted-over enclosure. The enclosure has some venting slats at the top and bottom. We don't even have the ability to pull open this front cover to clean behind it because it's been so painted shut.
What I want to do is buy polyurethane or neoprene foam sheets and attach them all over the radiator's enclosure so that the whole thing is basically dampening the high temperature when they clearly run the boiler too hot and too pressurized.
Does that make sense for reducing temperature? This way they stay open, no water hammer, and they don't freeze once it gets actually cold out. There is a riser pipe in the bathroom covered in polyethylene pool noodle so that was my inspiration.
Neoprene on its own doesn't exactly bond well so I'm looking at some of these neoprene or polyurethane squares with adhesive backing.
Additional context for why this is so serious: I can't sleep when the radiators go nuts. This is the second time in a week I've gone without sleep. By morning we are dehydrated, our throats dry, and it's like we've been walking outside in Vegas summer.
This is also not helped by cold, dry air coming in through open windows throughout the apartment. It's not enough. It was 46 degrees last night and the apartment was probably in the low 80s with five open windows.
Christmas Eve last year it reached 92 degrees in a unit on the first floor. That neighbor reported having severe migraines. A baby is at risk of SIDS from that kind of heat.

Blocking the vents could lead to dangerous heat build up in the radiators.  Your local health and building department might be a better choice because they can make the landlord fix them.  Trying to do it yourself opens you up to a lot of nasty stuff dealing with lawyers if something bad happens.

Considering a number of people say to throw welder blankets over radiators, I'm surprised by your view. How is this particularly different? It's not like I'm pouring cement over the whole thing.

Moreover, polyethylene foam is used to insulate pipes regularly. Do you have concerns that it will cause heat buildup in a riser?

@crip659 what danger do you imagine? They're clearly wet radiators not electric

I'm assuming that these are steam radiators, based on the description of hissing, so you don't have to worry about them overheating and setting something on fire.  Anything that prevents airflow through the radiator fins will cut down on the heating of your apartment.  You don't need something designed to insulate.  Cardboard or aluminum foil that covers the top or bottom vent openings will slow down the airflow, and cut down on heating.

Exactly. This is steam heat where there are copper pipes with fins behind this metal grate. It's baseboard-style, only not running along the baseboard—it's under windows.
The research I've done into these is they are not as energy-efficient as your typical cast iron. These don't retain heat long and require the boiler to run often compared to the cast irons. I would wager the whole system needs replacing. That's not happening anytime soon so I want to just reduce how much heat comes out of these grates into our living spaces every time the super runs the boiler too hard.

Some thermal mass in contact with the fins will slow down temperature cycling in your space; that can also block the convection and reduce total output. You may need insulation as well if even with the airflow blocked they're still too hot - I suspect you will. If there are small children or infirm people around, some insulation on the top of the housing might be a good idea anyway as it can get pretty hot to touch
